# Do not print "optimization terminated successfully" scipy.optimize.fmin?

Tags: python, scipy

Is there a way to "quietly" use scipy.optimize.fmin?
That is, that it does not print e.g.

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
        Current function value: 0.000000
        Iterations: 13
        Function evaluations: 30
```

when running the code?

This could be useful in e.g. loops that last a for a while.

Comment: How about `disp=False`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Setting the argument `disp=False` stops [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) from printing messages.